# Elements not getting hided on button click

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I have added show failures only button in report and trying to make it work so that when show failures is clicked it only shows failure cases.
But the button is not working as expected.
The control goes to the function but the intended functionality is not working as expected.
Please help in hiding the pass cases when this show failure button is clicked.

```html
 
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Mocha</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <style type="text/css">
        @charset "utf-8";

body {
  margin:0;
}

#mocha {
  font: 20px/1.5 "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 60px 50px;
}

#mocha ul,
#mocha li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#mocha ul {
  list-style: none;
}

#mocha h1,
#mocha h2 {
  margin: 0;
}

#mocha h1 {
  margin-top: 15px;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 200;
}

#mocha h1 a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

#mocha h1 a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

#mocha .suite .suite h1 {
  margin-top: 0;
  font-size: .8em;
}

#mocha .hidden {
  display: none;
}

#mocha h2 {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: normal;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#mocha .suite {
  margin-left: 15px;
}

#mocha .test {
  margin-left: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#mocha .test.pending:hover h2::after {
  content: '(pending)';
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
}

#mocha .test.pass.medium .duration {
  background: #c09853;
}

#mocha .test.pass.slow .duration {
  background: #b94a48;
}

#mocha .test.pass::before {
  content: '✓';
  font-size: 12px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 5px;
  color: #00d6b2;
}

#mocha .test.pass .duration {
  font-size: 9px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  padding: 2px 5px;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -ms-border-radius: 5px;
  -o-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#mocha .test.pass.fast .duration {
  display: none;
}

#mocha .test.pending {
  color: #0b97c4;
}

#mocha .test.pending::before {
  content: '◦';
  color: #0b97c4;
}

#mocha .test.fail {
  color: #c00;
}

#mocha .test.fail pre {
  color: black;
}

#mocha .test.fail::before {
  content: '✖';
  font-size: 12px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 5px;
  color: #c00;
}

#mocha .test pre.error {
  color: #c00;
  max-height: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
}

#mocha .test .html-error {
  overflow: auto;
  color: black;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  font: 12px/1.5 monaco, monospace;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  max-width: 85%; /*(1)*/
  max-width: -webkit-calc(100% - 42px);
  max-width: -moz-calc(100% - 42px);
  max-width: calc(100% - 42px); /*(2)*/
  max-height: 300px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  border-bottom-color: #ddd;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px #eee;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px #eee;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px #eee;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

#mocha .test .html-error pre.error {
  border: none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0;
  box-shadow: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: 18px;
  max-height: none;
}

/**
 * (1): approximate for browsers not supporting calc
 * (2): 42 = 2*15 + 2*10 + 2*1 (padding + margin + border)
 *      ^^ seriously
 */
#mocha .test pre {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  font: 12px/1.5 monaco, monospace;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  max-width: 85%; /*(1)*/
  max-width: -webkit-calc(100% - 42px);
  max-width: -moz-calc(100% - 42px);
  max-width: calc(100% - 42px); /*(2)*/
  word-wrap: break-word;
  border-bottom-color: #ddd;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px #eee;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px #eee;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px #eee;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

#mocha .test h2 {
  position: relative;
}

#mocha .test a.replay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  right: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: block;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  line-height: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #eee;
  font-size: 15px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
  -moz-border-radius: 15px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  -webkit-transition:opacity 200ms;
  -moz-transition:opacity 200ms;
  -o-transition:opacity 200ms;
  transition: opacity 200ms;
  opacity: 0.3;
  color: #888;
}

#mocha .test:hover a.replay {
  opacity: 1;
}

#mocha-report.pass .test.fail {
  display: none;
}

#mocha-report.fail .test.pass {
  display: none;
}

#mocha-report.pending .test.pass,
#mocha-report.pending .test.fail {
  display: none;
}
#mocha-report.pending .test.pass.pending {
  display: block;
}

#mocha-error {
  color: #c00;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: 100;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

#mocha-stats {
  position: fixed;
  top: 15px;
  right: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 0;
  color: #888;
  z-index: 1;
}

#mocha-stats .progress {
  float: right;
  padding-top: 0;

  /**
   * Set safe initial values, so mochas .progress does not inherit these
   * properties from Bootstrap .progress (which causes .progress height to
   * equal line height set in Bootstrap).
   */
  height: auto;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  background-color: initial;
}

#mocha-stats em {
  color: black;
}

#mocha-stats a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

#mocha-stats a:hover {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}

#mocha-stats li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 5px;
  list-style: none;
  padding-top: 11px;
}

#mocha-stats canvas {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}

#mocha code .comment { color: #ddd; }
#mocha code .init { color: #2f6fad; }
#mocha code .string { color: #5890ad; }
#mocha code .keyword { color: #8a6343; }
#mocha code .number { color: #2f6fad; }

@media screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
  #mocha {
    margin: 60px 0px;
  }

  #mocha #stats {
    position: absolute;
  }
}
#mocha .test.pass pre {
    display: none;
}

#mocha .test.fail pre {
    display: none;
}

#mocha .test pre.error {
    display: block;
}

#mocha .test .html-error pre.error {
    box-shadow: none;
}

#mocha .test:hover h2:after {
    color: #888888;
    content: "(view source)";
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 12px;
    position: relative;
    right: -10px;
    top: 0;
}

#mocha .test.pass.pending h2 {
    cursor: auto;
}

#mocha .mocha-header {
    right: 30px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 15px;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 0;
    color: #888;
    z-index: 1;
}

#mocha .mocha-header em {
    font-style: normal;
    color: black;
}

#mocha .mocha-header ul {
    display: inline-block;
}

#mocha .mocha-stats li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 5px;
    list-style: none;
    padding-top: 11px;
}

#mocha .mocha-menu {
    margin-right: 10px;
}

#mocha .mocha-menu li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 10px;
    list-style: none;
}

#mocha .mocha-menu li span {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 3px 7px 2px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    border-radius: 5px;
    user-select: none;
}

#mocha .mocha-menu li span.checked {
    box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}

#mocha .toggle-passes {
    background: #b94a48;
}

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="mocha">
            <div class="mocha-header">
                <ul class="mocha-menu">
                    <li><span id="toggle-passes" class="toggle-passes">show failures only</span></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="mocha-stats">
                    <li class="passes">passes: <em>6</em></li>
                    <li class="pending">pending: <em>1</em></li>
                    <li class="failures">failures: <em>1</em></li>
                    <li class="duration">duration: <em>15.3s</em></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <ul id="report"><li class="suite"><h1>Tests for apply(submit) endpoint.</h1><ul><li class="suite"><h1>/POST apply valid request with externalResumeID</h1><ul><li class="test pass pending"><h2>it should send 200 status</h2></li></ul></li><li class="suite"><h1>/POST apply valid request with base64</h1><ul><li class="test pass slow"><h2>it should send 200 status<span class="duration">2401ms</span></h2><pre><code>async function () {
      let email = chars[Math.floor(Math.random()*26)] + Math.random().toString(36).substring(2,11) + &#x27;@gmail.com&#x27;;
      const res = await request(baseUrl)
        .post(&#x27;services/apply&#x27;)
        .send({
          &#x22;firstName&#x22;: &#x22;Manny&#x22;,
          &#x22;lastName&#x22;: &#x22;Jackson&#x22;,
          &#x22;sourceid&#x22;: 48,
          &#x22;language&#x22;: &#x22;en&#x22;,
          &#x22;coverLetter&#x22;: &#x22;Testing cover letter&#x22;,
          &#x22;screenerParams&#x22;: {
            &#x22;7232706&#x22;: &#x22;9657234&#x22;,
            &#x22;7291179&#x22;: &#x22;9755492&#x22;,
            &#x22;7291180&#x22;: &#x22;9755499&#x22;,
            &#x22;7291181&#x22;: &#x22;9755503&#x22;,
            &#x22;7291182&#x22;: &#x22;9755507&#x22;,
            &#x22;7331140&#x22;: &#x22;vampire&#x22;,
            &#x22;7331142&#x22;: 6,
            &#x22;7331149&#x22;: &#x22;4/26/2019&#x22;,
            &#x22;7331150&#x22;: &#x22;588-765-3442&#x22;,
            &#x22;7367279&#x22;: &#x22;9877740&#x22;,
            &#x22;7367280&#x22;: &#x22;9877742&#x22;,
            &#x22;7367329&#x22;: &#x22;forestttt&#x22;,
            &#x22;seekerName&#x22;: &#x22;Jalen Jackson&#x22;,
            &#x22;seekerDate&#x22;: &#x22;4/26/2019&#x22;
          },
          &#x22;resume&#x22;: {
            &#x22;fileName&#x22;: &#x22;awesome-resume.pdf&#x22;,
            &#x22;base64&#x22;: &#x22;SmFsZW5zIHJlc3VtZQ==&#x22;
          },
          &#x22;email&#x22;: email,
          &#x22;jobDID&#x22;: &#x22;JHV53G6G77LC42J2W4C&#x22;,
          &#x22;tracking&#x22;: {},
          &#x22;device&#x22;:&#x22;desktop&#x22;,
          &#x22;userAgent&#x22;:&#x22;Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36&#x22;
        })
        .set(&#x27;Accept&#x27;, &#x27;application/json&#x27;)
        .set(&#x27;Authorization&#x27;, token)
        .expect(200);
      expect(res.body.message).to.be.eql(&#x27;Application submitted.&#x27;);
      return;
    }</code></pre></li></ul></li><li class="suite"><h1>/POST apply request without resume</h1><ul><li class="test pass slow"><h2>it should send 422 status<span class="duration">1238ms</span></h2><pre><code>async function () {
      const res = await request(baseUrl)
        .post(&#x27;services/apply&#x27;)
        .send({
          &#x22;firstName&#x22;: &#x22;testing&#x22;,
          &#x22;lastName&#x22;: &#x22;Reusme&#x22;,
          &#x22;sourceid&#x22;: null,
          &#x22;language&#x22;: &#x22;en&#x22;,
          &#x22;coverLetter&#x22;: null,
          &#x22;email&#x22;: &#x22;testingresume1@gmail.com&#x22;,
          &#x22;jobDID&#x22;: &#x22;JHV53G6G77LC42J2W4C&#x22;,
          &#x22;tracking&#x22;: {
            &#x22;VID&#x22;: &#x22;VX18158CB0FD8311EABE394901EE5EFF1F3580QJ&#x22;,
            &#x22;iPath&#x22;: &#x22;CRARBQ&#x22;,
            &#x22;siteID&#x22;: &#x22;cbnsv&#x22;,
            &#x22;hostSite&#x22;: &#x22;US&#x22;
          },
          &#x22;screenerParams&#x22;: {
            &#x22;seekeerName&#x22;: &#x22;testing Reusme&#x22;,
            &#x22;email&#x22;: &#x22;testingresume1@gmail.com&#x22;
          }
        })
        .set(&#x27;Accept&#x27;, &#x27;application/json&#x27;)
        .set(&#x27;Authorization&#x27;, token)
        .expect(422);
      expect(res.text).to.be.eql(&#x27;{&#x22;status&#x22;:422,&#x22;message&#x22;:&#x22;Cannot Proceed. No resume was attached&#x22;}&#x27;);
      return;
    }</code></pre></li></ul></li><li class="suite"><h1>/POST apply request without emailID</h1><ul><li class="test pass slow"><h2>it should send 422 status<span class="duration">1279ms</span></h2><pre><code>async function () {
      const res = await request(baseUrl)
        .post(&#x27;services/apply&#x27;)
        .send({
          &#x22;firstName&#x22;: &#x22;testing&#x22;,
          &#x22;lastName&#x22;: &#x22;Reusme&#x22;,
          &#x22;sourceid&#x22;: null,
          &#x22;language&#x22;: &#x22;en&#x22;,
          &#x22;coverLetter&#x22;: null,
          &#x22;jobDID&#x22;: &#x22;JHV53G6G77LC42J2W4C&#x22;,
          &#x22;resume&#x22;: {
            &#x22;externalUserID&#x22;: &#x22;XRCL5R66V4F25PNCQ647&#x22;,
            &#x22;externalResumeID&#x22;: &#x22;XRDF0J46M0BFFRP14NPM&#x22;
          },
          &#x22;tracking&#x22;: {
            &#x22;VID&#x22;: &#x22;VX18158CB0FD8311EABE394901EE5EFF1F3580QJ&#x22;,
            &#x22;iPath&#x22;: &#x22;CRARBQ&#x22;,
            &#x22;siteID&#x22;: &#x22;cbnsv&#x22;,
            &#x22;hostSite&#x22;: &#x22;US&#x22;
          },
          &#x22;screenerParams&#x22;: {
            &#x22;seekeerName&#x22;: &#x22;testing Reusme&#x22;,
            &#x22;email&#x22;: &#x22;testingresume1@gmail.com&#x22;
          }
        })
        .set(&#x27;Accept&#x27;, &#x27;application/json&#x27;)
        .set(&#x27;Authorization&#x27;, token)
        .expect(422);
      expect(res.text).to.be.eql(&#x27;{&#x22;status&#x22;:422,&#x22;message&#x22;:&#x22;No email present in the request&#x22;}&#x27;);
      return;
    }</code></pre></li></ul></li><li class="suite"><h1>/POST apply request without JobDID</h1><ul><li class="test pass slow"><h2>it should send 422 status<span class="duration">1315ms</span></h2><pre><code>async function () {
      const res = await request(baseUrl)
        .post(&#x27;services/apply&#x27;)
        .send({
          &#x22;firstName&#x22;: &#x22;testing&#x22;,
          &#x22;lastName&#x22;: &#x22;Reusme&#x22;,
          &#x22;sourceid&#x22;: null,
          &#x22;language&#x22;: &#x22;en&#x22;,
          &#x22;coverLetter&#x22;: null,
          &#x22;email&#x22;: &#x22;testingresume1@gmail.com&#x22;,
          &#x22;resume&#x22;: {
            &#x22;externalUserID&#x22;: &#x22;XRCL5R66V4F25PNCQ647&#x22;,
            &#x22;externalResumeID&#x22;: &#x22;XRDF0J46M0BFFRP14NPM&#x22;
          },
          &#x22;tracking&#x22;: {
            &#x22;VID&#x22;: &#x22;VX18158CB0FD8311EABE394901EE5EFF1F3580QJ&#x22;,
            &#x22;iPath&#x22;: &#x22;CRARBQ&#x22;,
            &#x22;siteID&#x22;: &#x22;cbnsv&#x22;,
            &#x22;hostSite&#x22;: &#x22;US&#x22;
          },
          &#x22;screenerParams&#x22;: {
            &#x22;seekeerName&#x22;: &#x22;testing Reusme&#x22;,
            &#x22;email&#x22;: &#x22;testingresume1@gmail.com&#x22;
          }
        })
        .set(&#x27;Accept&#x27;, &#x27;application/json&#x27;)
        .set(&#x27;Authorization&#x27;, token)
        .expect(422);
      expect(res.text).to.be.eql(&#x27;{&#x22;status&#x22;:422,&#x22;message&#x22;:&#x22;Please provide a valid jobDID&#x22;}&#x27;);
      return;
    }</code></pre></li></ul></li><li class="suite"><h1>/POST apply request with valid TNDID</h1><ul><li class="test pass slow"><h2>it should send 200 status<span class="duration">2903ms</span></h2><pre><code>async function () {
      let email = chars[Math.floor(Math.random()*26)] + Math.random().toString(36).substring(2,11) + &#x27;@gmail.com&#x27;;
      const res = await request(baseUrl)
        .post(&#x27;services/apply&#x27;)
        .send({
          &#x22;firstName&#x22;: &#x22;Aviral&#x22;,
          &#x22;lastName&#x22;: &#x22;Testing&#x22;,
          &#x22;sourceid&#x22;: 48,
          &#x22;language&#x22;: &#x22;en&#x22;,
          &#x22;coverLetter&#x22;: &#x22;Testing cover letter&#x22;,
          &#x22;screenerParams&#x22;: {
            &#x22;7232706&#x22;: &#x22;9657234&#x22;,
            &#x22;7291179&#x22;: &#x22;9755492&#x22;,
            &#x22;7291180&#x22;: &#x22;9755499&#x22;,
            &#x22;7291181&#x22;: &#x22;9755503&#x22;,
            &#x22;7291182&#x22;: &#x22;9755507&#x22;,
            &#x22;7331140&#x22;: &#x22;vampire&#x22;,
            &#x22;7331142&#x22;: 6,
            &#x22;7331149&#x22;: &#x22;4/26/2019&#x22;,
            &#x22;7331150&#x22;: &#x22;588-765-3442&#x22;,
            &#x22;7367279&#x22;: &#x22;9877740&#x22;,
            &#x22;7367280&#x22;: &#x22;9877742&#x22;,
            &#x22;7367329&#x22;: &#x22;forestttt&#x22;,
            &#x22;seekerName&#x22;: &#x22;Aviral Mani&#x22;,
            &#x22;seekerDate&#x22;: &#x22;4/26/2019&#x22;
          },
          &#x22;resume&#x22;: {
            &#x22;fileName&#x22;: &#x22;awesome-resume.pdf&#x22;,
            &#x22;base64&#x22;: &#x22;SmFsZW5zIHJlc3VtZQ==&#x22;
          },
          &#x22;email&#x22;: email,
          &#x22;jobDID&#x22;: &#x22;JHV53G6G77LC42J2W4C&#x22;,
          &#x22;tnDID&#x22;: &#x22;TNFT0JJQ52HZ8HRLL0D0&#x22;,
          &#x22;tracking&#x22;: {},
          &#x22;device&#x22;:&#x22;desktop&#x22;,
          &#x22;userAgent&#x22;:&#x22;Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36&#x22;
        })
        .set(&#x27;Accept&#x27;, &#x27;application/json&#x27;)
        .set(&#x27;Authorization&#x27;, token)
        .expect(200);
      return;
    }</code></pre></li></ul></li><li class="suite"><h1>/POST apply request with invalid TNDID</h1><ul><li class="test pass slow"><h2>it should send 422 status<span class="duration">2370ms</span></h2><pre><code>async function () {
      const res = await request(baseUrl)
        .post(&#x27;services/apply&#x27;)
        .send({
          &#x22;firstName&#x22;: &#x22;Aviral&#x22;,
          &#x22;lastName&#x22;: &#x22;Testing&#x22;,
          &#x22;sourceid&#x22;: 48,
          &#x22;language&#x22;: &#x22;en&#x22;,
          &#x22;coverLetter&#x22;: &#x22;Testing cover letter&#x22;,
          &#x22;screenerParams&#x22;: {
            &#x22;7232706&#x22;: &#x22;9657234&#x22;,
            &#x22;7291179&#x22;: &#x22;9755492&#x22;,
            &#x22;7291180&#x22;: &#x22;9755499&#x22;,
            &#x22;7291181&#x22;: &#x22;9755503&#x22;,
            &#x22;7291182&#x22;: &#x22;9755507&#x22;,
            &#x22;7331140&#x22;: &#x22;vampire&#x22;,
            &#x22;7331142&#x22;: 6,
            &#x22;7331149&#x22;: &#x22;4/26/2019&#x22;,
            &#x22;7331150&#x22;: &#x22;588-765-3442&#x22;,
            &#x22;7367279&#x22;: &#x22;9877740&#x22;,
            &#x22;7367280&#x22;: &#x22;9877742&#x22;,
            &#x22;7367329&#x22;: &#x22;forestttt&#x22;,
            &#x22;seekerName&#x22;: &#x22;Aviral Mani&#x22;,
            &#x22;seekerDate&#x22;: &#x22;4/26/2019&#x22;
          },
          &#x22;resume&#x22;: {
            &#x22;fileName&#x22;: &#x22;awesome-resume.pdf&#x22;,
            &#x22;base64&#x22;: &#x22;SmFsZW5zIHJlc3VtZQ==&#x22;
          },
          &#x22;email&#x22;: &#x22;AviralMani@mailinator.com&#x22;,
          &#x22;jobDID&#x22;: &#x22;JHV53G6G77LC42J2W4C&#x22;,
          &#x22;tnDID&#x22;: &#x22;someINVAILD&#x22;,
          &#x22;tracking&#x22;: {}
        })
        .set(&#x27;Accept&#x27;, &#x27;application/json&#x27;)
        .set(&#x27;Authorization&#x27;, token)
        .expect(422);
      expect(res.text).to.be.eql(&#x27;&#x22;{\\&#x22;error\\&#x22;:true,\\&#x22;message\\&#x22;:\\&#x22;Invalid jobDID or tnDID\\&#x22;}&#x22;&#x27;);
      return;
    }</code></pre></li></ul></li><li class="suite"><h1>/POST apply request without required screeners</h1><ul><li class="test fail"><h2>it should send 422 status</h2><pre><code>async function () {
      const res = await request(baseUrl)
        .post(&#x27;services/apply&#x27;)
        .send({
          &#x22;firstName&#x22;: &#x22;Aviral&#x22;,
          &#x22;lastName&#x22;: &#x22;Testing&#x22;,
          &#x22;sourceid&#x22;: 48,
          &#x22;language&#x22;: &#x22;en&#x22;,
          &#x22;coverLetter&#x22;: &#x22;Testing cover letter&#x22;,
          &#x22;resume&#x22;: {
            &#x22;fileName&#x22;: &#x22;awesome-resume.pdf&#x22;,
            &#x22;base64&#x22;: &#x22;SmFsZW5zIHJlc3VtZQ==&#x22;
          },
          &#x22;email&#x22;: &#x22;AviralMani@mailinator.com&#x22;,
          &#x22;jobDID&#x22;: &#x22;J2S7RM600YJ88HF5YKT&#x22;,
          &#x22;tracking&#x22;: {}
        })
        .set(&#x27;Accept&#x27;, &#x27;application/json&#x27;)
        .set(&#x27;Authorization&#x27;, token)
        .expect(422);
      expect(res.text).to.be.eql(&#x27;{&#x22;status&#x22;:422,&#x22;message&#x22;:&#x22;This job requires screeners. Please add screener params to the req body.&#x22;}&#x27;);
      return;
    }</code></pre><pre class="error">Error: expected &#x27;{&#x22;status&#x22;:422,&#x22;message&#x22;:&#x22;The job you requested was not found or expired&#x22;}&#x27; to sort of equal &#x27;{&#x22;status&#x22;:422,&#x22;message&#x22;:&#x22;This job requires screeners. Please add screener params to the req body.&#x22;}&#x27;
    at Assertion.assert (node_modules/expect.js/index.js:96:13)
    at Assertion.eql (node_modules/expect.js/index.js:230:10)
    at Function.eql (node_modules/expect.js/index.js:499:17)
    at Context.&#x3C;anonymous&#x3E; (test/apply.test.js:319:30)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)</pre></li></ul></li></ul></li></ul>
        </div>
        <script>
    function hideSuitesWithout(className) {
var suites = document.querySelectorAll('#report > .suite');

for (var i = 0; i < suites.length; i++) {
    let suite = suites[i];

    var els = suite.getElementsByClassName(className);
    if (!els.length) {
        suite.classList.add('hidden');
    }
}
}

function unhide() {
    var suites = document.getElementsByClassName('suite hidden');

    while (suites.length) {
        suites[0].classList.remove('hidden');
    }
}

function togglePasses() {
    var report = document.getElementById('report');

    report.classList.toggle('hide-passes');

    if (report.classList.contains('hide-passes')) {
        hideSuitesWithout('test fail');
    } else {
        unhide();
    }
}

document.getElementById('toggle-passes').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    this.classList.toggle('checked');

    togglePasses();
});

var tests = document.getElementsByClassName('test');

for (var i = 0; i < tests.length; i++) {
    var elem = tests[i];
    var head = elem.children[0];

    head.onclick = function () {
        var code = this.parentElement.children[1];
        var display = code.style.display;

        if (display && display === 'block') {
            code.style.display = 'none';
        } else {
            code.style.display = 'block';
        }
    };
}
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: your code is not readable

Comment: Try doing this forcefully checkout this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle

Comment: @RaymondShafiee Shafiee  the code snippet i have attached works and ill format it

Comment: @AliHussnain could you answer in code as. to how,

Comment: check this out for forcefully toggle the class `this.classList.toggle('checked',true)`

Comment: @AliHussnain it doesnt work

Comment: @art I just checked by inspecting the element and it's working as expected it's adding a `checked` class to the element you have referenced and that is button.
I'm not sure if you suppose to have the class in other element.

Comment: @AliHussnain can you answer it i will accept the answer

Comment: No I just tried your attached snippet and inspected the elements in browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
 
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Mocha</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <style type="text/css">
        @charset "utf-8";

body {
  margin:0;
}

#mocha {
  font: 20px/1.5 "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 60px 50px;
}

#mocha ul,
#mocha li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#mocha ul {
  list-style: none;
}

#mocha h1,
#mocha h2 {
  margin: 0;
}

#mocha h1 {
  margin-top: 15px;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 200;
}

#mocha h1 a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

#mocha h1 a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

#mocha .suite .suite h1 {
  margin-top: 0;
  font-size: .8em;
}

#mocha .hidden {
  display: none;
}

#mocha h2 {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: normal;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#mocha .suite {
  margin-left: 15px;
}

#mocha .test {
  margin-left: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#mocha .test.pending:hover h2::after {
  content: '(pending)';
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
}

#mocha .test.pass.medium .duration {
  background: #c09853;
}

#mocha .test.pass.slow .duration {
  background: #b94a48;
}

#mocha .test.pass::before {
  content: '✓';
  font-size: 12px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 5px;
  color: #00d6b2;
}

#mocha .test.pass .duration {
  font-size: 9px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  padding: 2px 5px;
  color: #fff;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -ms-border-radius: 5px;
  -o-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#mocha .test.pass.fast .duration {
  display: none;
}

#mocha .test.pending {
  color: #0b97c4;
}

#mocha .test.pending::before {
  content: '◦';
  color: #0b97c4;
}

#mocha .test.fail {
  color: #c00;
}

#mocha .test.fail pre {
  color: black;
}

#mocha .test.fail::before {
  content: '✖';
  font-size: 12px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 5px;
  color: #c00;
}

#mocha .test pre.error {
  color: #c00;
  max-height: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
}

#mocha .test .html-error {
  overflow: auto;
  color: black;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  font: 12px/1.5 monaco, monospace;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  max-width: 85%; /*(1)*/
  max-width: -webkit-calc(100% - 42px);
  max-width: -moz-calc(100% - 42px);
  max-width: calc(100% - 42px); /*(2)*/
  max-height: 300px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  border-bottom-color: #ddd;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px #eee;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px #eee;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px #eee;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

#mocha .test .html-error pre.error {
  border: none;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0;
  box-shadow: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: 18px;
  max-height: none;
}

/**
 * (1): approximate for browsers not supporting calc
 * (2): 42 = 2*15 + 2*10 + 2*1 (padding + margin + border)
 *      ^^ seriously
 */
#mocha .test pre {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  font: 12px/1.5 monaco, monospace;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  max-width: 85%; /*(1)*/
  max-width: -webkit-calc(100% - 42px);
  max-width: -moz-calc(100% - 42px);
  max-width: calc(100% - 42px); /*(2)*/
  word-wrap: break-word;
  border-bottom-color: #ddd;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px #eee;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px #eee;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px #eee;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

#mocha .test h2 {
  position: relative;
}

#mocha .test a.replay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  right: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: block;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  line-height: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #eee;
  font-size: 15px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
  -moz-border-radius: 15px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  -webkit-transition:opacity 200ms;
  -moz-transition:opacity 200ms;
  -o-transition:opacity 200ms;
  transition: opacity 200ms;
  opacity: 0.3;
  color: #888;
}

#mocha .test:hover a.replay {
  opacity: 1;
}

#mocha-report.pass .test.fail {
  display: none;
}

#mocha-report.fail .test.pass {
  display: none;
}

#mocha-report.pending .test.pass,
#mocha-report.pending .test.fail {
  display: none;
}
#mocha-report.pending .test.pass.pending {
  display: block;
}

#mocha-error {
  color: #c00;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: 100;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

#mocha-stats {
  position: fixed;
  top: 15px;
  right: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 0;
  color: #888;
  z-index: 1;
}

#mocha-stats .progress {
  float: right;
  padding-top: 0;

  /**
   * Set safe initial values, so mochas .progress does not inherit these
   * properties from Bootstrap .progress (which causes .progress height to
   * equal line height set in Bootstrap).
   */
  height: auto;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  background-color: initial;
}

#mocha-stats em {
  color: black;
}

#mocha-stats a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

#mocha-stats a:hover {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}

#mocha-stats li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 5px;
  list-style: none;
  padding-top: 11px;
}

#mocha-stats canvas {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}

#mocha code .comment { color: #ddd; }
#mocha code .init { color: #2f6fad; }
#mocha code .string { color: #5890ad; }
#mocha code .keyword { color: #8a6343; }
#mocha code .number { color: #2f6fad; }

@media screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
  #mocha {
    margin: 60px 0px;
  }

  #mocha #stats {
    position: absolute;
  }
}
#mocha .test.pass pre {
    display: none;
}

#mocha .test.fail pre {
    display: none;
}

#mocha .test pre.error {
    display: block;
}

#mocha .test .html-error pre.error {
    box-shadow: none;
}

#mocha .test:hover h2:after {
    color: #888888;
    content: "(view source)";
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 12px;
    position: relative;
    right: -10px;
    top: 0;
}

#mocha .test.pass.pending h2 {
    cursor: auto;
}

#mocha .mocha-header {
    right: 30px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 15px;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 0;
    color: #888;
    z-index: 1;
}

#mocha .mocha-header em {
    font-style: normal;
    color: black;
}

#mocha .mocha-header ul {
    display: inline-block;
}

#mocha .mocha-stats li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 5px;
    list-style: none;
    padding-top: 11px;
}

#mocha .mocha-menu {
    margin-right: 10px;
}

#mocha .mocha-menu li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 10px;
    list-style: none;
}

#mocha .mocha-menu li span {
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 3px 7px 2px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    border-radius: 5px;
    user-select: none;
}

#mocha .mocha-menu li span.checked {
    box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}

#mocha .toggle-passes {
    background: #b94a48;
}

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="mocha">
            <div class="mocha-header">
                <ul class="mocha-menu">
                    <li><span id="toggle-passes" class="toggle-passes">show failures only</span></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="mocha-stats">
                    <li class="passes">passes: <em>6</em></li>
                    <li class="pending">pending: <em>1</em></li>
                    <li class="failures">failures: <em>1</em></li>
                    <li class="duration">duration: <em>15.3s</em></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <ul id="report"><li class="suite"><h1>Tests for apply(submit) endpoint.</h1><ul><li class="suite"><h1>/POST apply valid request with externalResumeID</h1><ul><li class="test pass pending"><h2>it should send 200 status</h2></li></ul></li><li class="suite"><h1>/POST apply valid request with base64</h1><ul><li class="test pass slow"><h2>it should send 200 status<span class="duration">2401ms</span></h2><pre><code>async function () {
      let email = chars[Math.floor(Math.random()*26)] + Math.random().toString(36).substring(2,11) + &#x27;@gmail.com&#x27;;
      const res = await request(baseUrl)
        .post(&#x27;services/apply&#x27;)
        .send({
          &#x22;firstName&#x22;: &#x22;Manny&#x22;,
          &#x22;lastName&#x22;: &#x22;Jackson&#x22;,
          &#x22;sourceid&#x22;: 48,
          &#x22;language&#x22;: &#x22;en&#x22;,
          &#x22;coverLetter&#x22;: &#x22;Testing cover letter&#x22;,
          &#x22;screenerParams&#x22;: {
            &#x22;7232706&#x22;: &#x22;9657234&#x22;,
            &#x22;7291179&#x22;: &#x22;9755492&#x22;,
            &#x22;7291180&#x22;: &#x22;9755499&#x22;,
            &#x22;7291181&#x22;: &#x22;9755503&#x22;,
            &#x22;7291182&#x22;: &#x22;9755507&#x22;,
            &#x22;7331140&#x22;: &#x22;vampire&#x22;,
            &#x22;7331142&#x22;: 6,
            &#x22;7331149&#x22;: &#x22;4/26/2019&#x22;,
            &#x22;7331150&#x22;: &#x22;588-765-3442&#x22;,
            &#x22;7367279&#x22;: &#x22;9877740&#x22;,
            &#x22;7367280&#x22;: &#x22;9877742&#x22;,
            &#x22;7367329&#x22;: &#x22;forestttt&#x22;,
            &#x22;seekerName&#x22;: &#x22;Jalen Jackson&#x22;,
            &#x22;seekerDate&#x22;: &#x22;4/26/2019&#x22;
          },
          &#x22;resume&#x22;: {
            &#x22;fileName&#x22;: &#x22;awesome-resume.pdf&#x22;,
            &#x22;base64&#x22;: &#x22;SmFsZW5zIHJlc3VtZQ==&#x22;
          },
          &#x22;email&#x22;: email,
          &#x22;jobDID&#x22;: &#x22;JHV53G6G77LC42J2W4C&#x22;,
          &#x22;tracking&#x22;: {},
          &#x22;device&#x22;:&#x22;desktop&#x22;,
          &#x22;userAgent&#x22;:&#x22;Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36&#x22;
        })
        .set(&#x27;Accept&#x27;, &#x27;application/json&#x27;)
        .set(&#x27;Authorization&#x27;, token)
        .expect(200);
      expect(res.body.message).to.be.eql(&#x27;Application submitted.&#x27;);
      return;
    }</code></pre></li></ul></li><li class="suite"><h1>/POST apply request without resume</h1><ul><li class="test pass slow"><h2>it should send 422 status<span class="duration">1238ms</span></h2><pre><code>async function () {
      const res = await request(baseUrl)
        .post(&#x27;services/apply&#x27;)
        .send({
          &#x22;firstName&#x22;: &#x22;testing&#x22;,
          &#x22;lastName&#x22;: &#x22;Reusme&#x22;,
          &#x22;sourceid&#x22;: null,
          &#x22;language&#x22;: &#x22;en&#x22;,
          &#x22;coverLetter&#x22;: null,
          &#x22;email&#x22;: &#x22;testingresume1@gmail.com&#x22;,
          &#x22;jobDID&#x22;: &#x22;JHV53G6G77LC42J2W4C&#x22;,
          &#x22;tracking&#x22;: {
            &#x22;VID&#x22;: &#x22;VX18158CB0FD8311EABE394901EE5EFF1F3580QJ&#x22;,
            &#x22;iPath&#x22;: &#x22;CRARBQ&#x22;,
            &#x22;siteID&#x22;: &#x22;cbnsv&#x22;,
            &#x22;hostSite&#x22;: &#x22;US&#x22;
          },
          &#x22;screenerParams&#x22;: {
            &#x22;seekeerName&#x22;: &#x22;testing Reusme&#x22;,
            &#x22;email&#x22;: &#x22;testingresume1@gmail.com&#x22;
          }
        })
        .set(&#x27;Accept&#x27;, &#x27;application/json&#x27;)
        .set(&#x27;Authorization&#x27;, token)
        .expect(422);
      expect(res.text).to.be.eql(&#x27;{&#x22;status&#x22;:422,&#x22;message&#x22;:&#x22;Cannot Proceed. No resume was attached&#x22;}&#x27;);
      return;
    }</code></pre></li></ul></li><li class="suite"><h1>/POST apply request without emailID</h1><ul><li class="test pass slow"><h2>it should send 422 status<span class="duration">1279ms</span></h2><pre><code>async function () {
      const res = await request(baseUrl)
        .post(&#x27;services/apply&#x27;)
        .send({
          &#x22;firstName&#x22;: &#x22;testing&#x22;,
          &#x22;lastName&#x22;: &#x22;Reusme&#x22;,
          &#x22;sourceid&#x22;: null,
          &#x22;language&#x22;: &#x22;en&#x22;,
          &#x22;coverLetter&#x22;: null,
          &#x22;jobDID&#x22;: &#x22;JHV53G6G77LC42J2W4C&#x22;,
          &#x22;resume&#x22;: {
            &#x22;externalUserID&#x22;: &#x22;XRCL5R66V4F25PNCQ647&#x22;,
            &#x22;externalResumeID&#x22;: &#x22;XRDF0J46M0BFFRP14NPM&#x22;
          },
          &#x22;tracking&#x22;: {
            &#x22;VID&#x22;: &#x22;VX18158CB0FD8311EABE394901EE5EFF1F3580QJ&#x22;,
            &#x22;iPath&#x22;: &#x22;CRARBQ&#x22;,
            &#x22;siteID&#x22;: &#x22;cbnsv&#x22;,
            &#x22;hostSite&#x22;: &#x22;US&#x22;
          },
          &#x22;screenerParams&#x22;: {
            &#x22;seekeerName&#x22;: &#x22;testing Reusme&#x22;,
            &#x22;email&#x22;: &#x22;testingresume1@gmail.com&#x22;
          }
        })
        .set(&#x27;Accept&#x27;, &#x27;application/json&#x27;)
        .set(&#x27;Authorization&#x27;, token)
        .expect(422);
      expect(res.text).to.be.eql(&#x27;{&#x22;status&#x22;:422,&#x22;message&#x22;:&#x22;No email present in the request&#x22;}&#x27;);
      return;
    }</code></pre></li></ul></li><li class="suite"><h1>/POST apply request without JobDID</h1><ul><li class="test pass slow"><h2>it should send 422 status<span class="duration">1315ms</span></h2><pre><code>async function () {
      const res = await request(baseUrl)
        .post(&#x27;services/apply&#x27;)
        .send({
          &#x22;firstName&#x22;: &#x22;testing&#x22;,
          &#x22;lastName&#x22;: &#x22;Reusme&#x22;,
          &#x22;sourceid&#x22;: null,
          &#x22;language&#x22;: &#x22;en&#x22;,
          &#x22;coverLetter&#x22;: null,
          &#x22;email&#x22;: &#x22;testingresume1@gmail.com&#x22;,
          &#x22;resume&#x22;: {
            &#x22;externalUserID&#x22;: &#x22;XRCL5R66V4F25PNCQ647&#x22;,
            &#x22;externalResumeID&#x22;: &#x22;XRDF0J46M0BFFRP14NPM&#x22;
          },
          &#x22;tracking&#x22;: {
            &#x22;VID&#x22;: &#x22;VX18158CB0FD8311EABE394901EE5EFF1F3580QJ&#x22;,
            &#x22;iPath&#x22;: &#x22;CRARBQ&#x22;,
            &#x22;siteID&#x22;: &#x22;cbnsv&#x22;,
            &#x22;hostSite&#x22;: &#x22;US&#x22;
          },
          &#x22;screenerParams&#x22;: {
            &#x22;seekeerName&#x22;: &#x22;testing Reusme&#x22;,
            &#x22;email&#x22;: &#x22;testingresume1@gmail.com&#x22;
          }
        })
        .set(&#x27;Accept&#x27;, &#x27;application/json&#x27;)
        .set(&#x27;Authorization&#x27;, token)
        .expect(422);
      expect(res.text).to.be.eql(&#x27;{&#x22;status&#x22;:422,&#x22;message&#x22;:&#x22;Please provide a valid jobDID&#x22;}&#x27;);
      return;
    }</code></pre></li></ul></li><li class="suite"><h1>/POST apply request with valid TNDID</h1><ul><li class="test pass slow"><h2>it should send 200 status<span class="duration">2903ms</span></h2><pre><code>async function () {
      let email = chars[Math.floor(Math.random()*26)] + Math.random().toString(36).substring(2,11) + &#x27;@gmail.com&#x27;;
      const res = await request(baseUrl)
        .post(&#x27;services/apply&#x27;)
        .send({
          &#x22;firstName&#x22;: &#x22;Aviral&#x22;,
          &#x22;lastName&#x22;: &#x22;Testing&#x22;,
          &#x22;sourceid&#x22;: 48,
          &#x22;language&#x22;: &#x22;en&#x22;,
          &#x22;coverLetter&#x22;: &#x22;Testing cover letter&#x22;,
          &#x22;screenerParams&#x22;: {
            &#x22;7232706&#x22;: &#x22;9657234&#x22;,
            &#x22;7291179&#x22;: &#x22;9755492&#x22;,
            &#x22;7291180&#x22;: &#x22;9755499&#x22;,
            &#x22;7291181&#x22;: &#x22;9755503&#x22;,
            &#x22;7291182&#x22;: &#x22;9755507&#x22;,
            &#x22;7331140&#x22;: &#x22;vampire&#x22;,
            &#x22;7331142&#x22;: 6,
            &#x22;7331149&#x22;: &#x22;4/26/2019&#x22;,
            &#x22;7331150&#x22;: &#x22;588-765-3442&#x22;,
            &#x22;7367279&#x22;: &#x22;9877740&#x22;,
            &#x22;7367280&#x22;: &#x22;9877742&#x22;,
            &#x22;7367329&#x22;: &#x22;forestttt&#x22;,
            &#x22;seekerName&#x22;: &#x22;Aviral Mani&#x22;,
            &#x22;seekerDate&#x22;: &#x22;4/26/2019&#x22;
          },
          &#x22;resume&#x22;: {
            &#x22;fileName&#x22;: &#x22;awesome-resume.pdf&#x22;,
            &#x22;base64&#x22;: &#x22;SmFsZW5zIHJlc3VtZQ==&#x22;
          },
          &#x22;email&#x22;: email,
          &#x22;jobDID&#x22;: &#x22;JHV53G6G77LC42J2W4C&#x22;,
          &#x22;tnDID&#x22;: &#x22;TNFT0JJQ52HZ8HRLL0D0&#x22;,
          &#x22;tracking&#x22;: {},
          &#x22;device&#x22;:&#x22;desktop&#x22;,
          &#x22;userAgent&#x22;:&#x22;Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.110 Safari/537.36&#x22;
        })
        .set(&#x27;Accept&#x27;, &#x27;application/json&#x27;)
        .set(&#x27;Authorization&#x27;, token)
        .expect(200);
      return;
    }</code></pre></li></ul></li><li class="suite"><h1>/POST apply request with invalid TNDID</h1><ul><li class="test pass slow"><h2>it should send 422 status<span class="duration">2370ms</span></h2><pre><code>async function () {
      const res = await request(baseUrl)
        .post(&#x27;services/apply&#x27;)
        .send({
          &#x22;firstName&#x22;: &#x22;Aviral&#x22;,
          &#x22;lastName&#x22;: &#x22;Testing&#x22;,
          &#x22;sourceid&#x22;: 48,
          &#x22;language&#x22;: &#x22;en&#x22;,
          &#x22;coverLetter&#x22;: &#x22;Testing cover letter&#x22;,
          &#x22;screenerParams&#x22;: {
            &#x22;7232706&#x22;: &#x22;9657234&#x22;,
            &#x22;7291179&#x22;: &#x22;9755492&#x22;,
            &#x22;7291180&#x22;: &#x22;9755499&#x22;,
            &#x22;7291181&#x22;: &#x22;9755503&#x22;,
            &#x22;7291182&#x22;: &#x22;9755507&#x22;,
            &#x22;7331140&#x22;: &#x22;vampire&#x22;,
            &#x22;7331142&#x22;: 6,
            &#x22;7331149&#x22;: &#x22;4/26/2019&#x22;,
            &#x22;7331150&#x22;: &#x22;588-765-3442&#x22;,
            &#x22;7367279&#x22;: &#x22;9877740&#x22;,
            &#x22;7367280&#x22;: &#x22;9877742&#x22;,
            &#x22;7367329&#x22;: &#x22;forestttt&#x22;,
            &#x22;seekerName&#x22;: &#x22;Aviral Mani&#x22;,
            &#x22;seekerDate&#x22;: &#x22;4/26/2019&#x22;
          },
          &#x22;resume&#x22;: {
            &#x22;fileName&#x22;: &#x22;awesome-resume.pdf&#x22;,
            &#x22;base64&#x22;: &#x22;SmFsZW5zIHJlc3VtZQ==&#x22;
          },
          &#x22;email&#x22;: &#x22;AviralMani@mailinator.com&#x22;,
          &#x22;jobDID&#x22;: &#x22;JHV53G6G77LC42J2W4C&#x22;,
          &#x22;tnDID&#x22;: &#x22;someINVAILD&#x22;,
          &#x22;tracking&#x22;: {}
        })
        .set(&#x27;Accept&#x27;, &#x27;application/json&#x27;)
        .set(&#x27;Authorization&#x27;, token)
        .expect(422);
      expect(res.text).to.be.eql(&#x27;&#x22;{\\&#x22;error\\&#x22;:true,\\&#x22;message\\&#x22;:\\&#x22;Invalid jobDID or tnDID\\&#x22;}&#x22;&#x27;);
      return;
    }</code></pre></li></ul></li><li class="suite"><h1>/POST apply request without required screeners</h1><ul><li class="test fail"><h2>it should send 422 status</h2><pre><code>async function () {
      const res = await request(baseUrl)
        .post(&#x27;services/apply&#x27;)
        .send({
          &#x22;firstName&#x22;: &#x22;Aviral&#x22;,
          &#x22;lastName&#x22;: &#x22;Testing&#x22;,
          &#x22;sourceid&#x22;: 48,
          &#x22;language&#x22;: &#x22;en&#x22;,
          &#x22;coverLetter&#x22;: &#x22;Testing cover letter&#x22;,
          &#x22;resume&#x22;: {
            &#x22;fileName&#x22;: &#x22;awesome-resume.pdf&#x22;,
            &#x22;base64&#x22;: &#x22;SmFsZW5zIHJlc3VtZQ==&#x22;
          },
          &#x22;email&#x22;: &#x22;AviralMani@mailinator.com&#x22;,
          &#x22;jobDID&#x22;: &#x22;J2S7RM600YJ88HF5YKT&#x22;,
          &#x22;tracking&#x22;: {}
        })
        .set(&#x27;Accept&#x27;, &#x27;application/json&#x27;)
        .set(&#x27;Authorization&#x27;, token)
        .expect(422);
      expect(res.text).to.be.eql(&#x27;{&#x22;status&#x22;:422,&#x22;message&#x22;:&#x22;This job requires screeners. Please add screener params to the req body.&#x22;}&#x27;);
      return;
    }</code></pre><pre class="error">Error: expected &#x27;{&#x22;status&#x22;:422,&#x22;message&#x22;:&#x22;The job you requested was not found or expired&#x22;}&#x27; to sort of equal &#x27;{&#x22;status&#x22;:422,&#x22;message&#x22;:&#x22;This job requires screeners. Please add screener params to the req body.&#x22;}&#x27;
    at Assertion.assert (node_modules/expect.js/index.js:96:13)
    at Assertion.eql (node_modules/expect.js/index.js:230:10)
    at Function.eql (node_modules/expect.js/index.js:499:17)
    at Context.&#x3C;anonymous&#x3E; (test/apply.test.js:319:30)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)</pre></li></ul></li></ul></li></ul>
        </div>
        <script>
    function hideSuitesWithout(className) {
var suites = document.querySelectorAll('#report .suite');

for (var i = 0; i < suites.length; i++) {
    let suite = suites[i];

    var els = suite.getElementsByClassName(className);
    if (!els.length) {
        suite.classList.add('hidden');
    }
}
}

function unhide() {
    var suites = document.getElementsByClassName('suite hidden');

    while (suites.length) {
        suites[0].classList.remove('hidden');
    }
}

function togglePasses() {
    var report = document.getElementById('report');

    report.classList.toggle('hide-passes');

    if (report.classList.contains('hide-passes')) {
        hideSuitesWithout('test fail');
    } else {
        unhide();
    }
}

document.getElementById('toggle-passes').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    this.classList.toggle('checked');

    togglePasses();
});

var tests = document.getElementsByClassName('test');

for (var i = 0; i < tests.length; i++) {
    var elem = tests[i];
    var head = elem.children[0];

    head.onclick = function () {
        var code = this.parentElement.children[1];
        var display = code.style.display;

        if (display && display === 'block') {
            code.style.display = 'none';
        } else {
            code.style.display = 'block';
        }
    };
}
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Next time don't hesitate to leave a note on what you have done in the code.

Comment: @MaximeChevallier Please check my other answers on this question.

Comment: Ow, sorry I tough it was 2 differents personns. You can merge your answers so :)

Answer (score 0):

Add this css style to hide pass cases:

```
.hide-passes {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: not working,   it hides all report.

Comment: Oh.. then update `var suites = document.querySelectorAll('#report > .suite');` to `var suites = document.querySelectorAll('#report .suite');`. just remove `>`.

Comment: still the same , if it works for you please attach snippet.Thanks